# Error when attempting to Publish Customizations (Cannot access the uploaded file)

Tags: acumatica

We've recently created a second Company (id=3) based on a snapshot of our original company (id=2). I am attempting to publish a change to one of the Customization Projects in the new company. The file upload/save worked fine, but publishing leads to this error:

```
Publish Customization

Compiled projects: AA, BB, CC, DD     

Validation has been started.

PX.Data.PXException: Cannot access the uploaded file. Failed to get the 
latest revision of the file 9a65331c-ad34-477c-9759-2c414dead49f

   at Customization.CstBinFile.GetFileFromDb()
   at Customization.CstBinFile.SaveFiles(FilesCollection context)
   at Customization.CstDocument.GetFiles(FilesCollection context)
   at Customization.CstManager.ValidateDocument(CstDocument doc, Action`1 

    logMessageDelegate, Boolean patchLibInDB)
  at PX.Customization.CstValidationProcess.ValidateCurrentDocument(Action`1 
logMessage)
   at PX.Customization.CstValidationProcess.CompileInternal()
   at PX.Customization.CstValidationProcess.<>c__DisplayClass6_0. 
<ProcessRequest>b__0()
```

This attempt represents the first publish within this Company. 
I retried the upload/save, but still no luck.
Our version is:  6.10.0010.

How do I overcome this error? 
Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you manually updated/changed files in Customization's zip?

Comment: Just note the customization for one company will publish for all with the exception of database records (sitemap, import scenarios, etc.). So you might not need to publish your customization package (same package) for 2 companies. Just a thought if it provides a work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when the customization projects reference a file that has been removed from the database. Customization project still has the file reference ID but the database doesn't contain a file associated with that ID anymore.

If this is the cause of your error, you can correct it by removing and adding back missing files. To do this, go to the Files section of your customization project. Click on each file link.

If the file is missing in database, an error message popup will appear. For these, remove the file link reference and add it back again. When files are not missing, they will appear like in the screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you!!